# Why are calls to unmanged code so slow in sql clr assembly

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, unmanaged

When testing the performance in SQL clr assembly it seems that call to unmaged code is extrem slow

I did the test as console app and as clr assembly with the following result

Console App:

1. decimal.Parse("-49823174320.9293800") 304.7 ns 855.7 cycles
2. PInvoke.Empty()...........................................11.9 ns  33.6 cycles

Clr assembly:

1. decimal.Parse("-49823174320.9293800") 304.7 ns 855.7 cycles
2. PInvoke.Empty()......................................5095.4 ns 14308.1 cycles

The PInvoke.Empty() is an asm function with only ret statement. This function is created with virtualAlloc.

```
public static class Pinvoke
{
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate ulong FuncUInt64();

    private const uint PAGE_EXECUTE = 0x10;
    private const uint PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40;
    private const uint MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000;
    private const uint MEM_RELEASE = 0x8000;

    public static readonly FuncUInt64 Empty;
    private static readonly byte[] ReturnOnlyAsm = {  0xC3 };

    static Pinvoke()
    {
        var buf = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            // We pad the functions to 64 bytes (the length of a cacheline on the Intel processors)
            var rdtscpLength = (ReturnOnlyAsm.Length & 63) != 0 ? (ReturnOnlyAsm.Length | 63) + 1 : ReturnOnlyAsm.Length;

            buf = VirtualAlloc(IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr) rdtscpLength, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
            if (buf == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();


            Marshal.Copy(ReturnOnlyAsm, 0, buf, ReturnOnlyAsm.Length);
            for (var i = ReturnOnlyAsm.Length; i < rdtscpLength; i++) Marshal.WriteByte(buf, i, 0x90); // nop

            // Change the access of the allocated memory from R/W to Execute
            var result = VirtualProtect(buf, (IntPtr) rdtscpLength, PAGE_EXECUTE, out var oldProtection);
            if (!result) throw new Win32Exception();

            // Create a delegate to the "function"
            Empty = (FuncUInt64) Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(buf, typeof(FuncUInt64));

            buf = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (buf != IntPtr.Zero)
                VirtualFree(buf, IntPtr.Zero, MEM_RELEASE);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr VirtualAlloc(IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool VirtualProtect(IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, uint flAllocationType, out uint lpflOldProtect);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool VirtualFree(IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, uint dwFreeType);
}
```

The decimal parse has no unmanged code but the GetTimestamp has. Calls to unmanged code seems to be more than 250 times slower

For code used to test see https://github.com/Anderman/SqlClrPerformance.
This code used asm code trick to call the rdtscp timer and will only run on 64 bit.

Used sql server 2017 (13.0.1742.0) and tested with release build for both sql and console app.

Also tested with a the Stopwatch which is not so accurate, but reveals the same issue

```
 private void swGetCurrentProcess()
        {
            var i = 0;
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            do
            {
                i++;
                Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            } while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 5000);
            var nanoSecodsPerIteration = 5_000_000_000 / i;

            _reporter($"GetCurrentProcess with StopWatch {nanoSecodsPerIteration,5:0.0} ns ");
        }
```

Console:

GetCurrentProcess with StopWatch 426.0 ns

SqlClr:

GetCurrentProcess with StopWatch 12422.0 ns

Comment: Are you calling this just once? Also can you also show your code your using to test this

Comment: would [this answer apply](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84700)? "...the most important thin[g] is to remember that SQL Server is a cooperative multi-tasking environment, while CLR is not. The SQLCLR code must call Thread.BeginThreadAffinity() anytime it hogs the CPU for any duration (including blocking)..."

Comment: The stopwatch code is not only native, it is also I/O bound. Would it run considerably faster if you used [DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,138) instead of Stopwatch? The we could narrow it down further.

Comment: What version of SQL Server, incidentally? Different versions use different versions of the CLR.

Comment: Did you profile a Debug or Release build?

Comment: @dlatikay I am not using Thread.BeginThreadAffinity(), If I understand this correct. You can used this to run a thread under windowOS instead of SQLOS

Comment: @dlatikay. It is not IO bound. I tested with an empty PInvoke Call. See Github repository

Comment: Just to verify that invoking `RDTSC` doesn't get you in trouble with SQL Server's own scheduling when P/Invoking, have you tried upping the length of the test and using simple wall clock time to benchmark (that is, `SELECT SYSUTCDATETIME()`) in SQL Server? Another thing to try is invoking an already established function that does little to nothing, like `GetCurrentProcess`. If that is fast, the fact that you're calling into dynamically generated code may have something to do with it. (C++/CLR would simplify these things anyway, but I'm guessing mixed assemblies won't work in SQL.)

Comment: @Jeroen. I did a test with the Stopwatch from .net. for 5 seconds and call Process.GetCurrentProcess(). This has still the same result

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of is attaching a debugger to SQL Server and seeing if `Debugger.Break` will cooperate. Walk the stack frame to see if there's anything interesting up there -- SQL Server performs its own CLR hosting, after all. However, it seems unlikely that, even if you found the cause, there was some way to remedy it using a server setting or modification of your code, so it may be worthwhile to consider rethinking your current strategy altogether -- that is, find a way to sharply reduce the number of unmanaged calls needed, especially in loops.